# How to subset a row from list based on condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` `outcome`, which has a column called `hospital`. and a column called `state`. The `outcome` has been sorted already. Now I want to subset the nth `hospital` from each `state`(if there's not a Nth then returns NA for that state). I try to solve it the below way.(Since this is a homework, I just showed the third branch that causes mistake).

```
rankall <- function(out, num = "best"){
    outcome <- readdata(outcome = out)  //returns a data.table sorted by rate
   ...
    outcome <- lapply(outcome, function(x) ifelse(num <= nrow(x), x[num,], c(NA,NA)))
    outcome <- rbindlist(outcome)
}
```

The original `outcome` is like

```
> data
                                               hospital state
   1:                              NYU HOSPITALS CENTER    NY
   2:                               DOYLESTOWN HOSPITAL    PA
   3:          AVERA HEART HOSPITAL OF SOUTH DAKOTA LLC    SD
   4:                 GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER    CA
   5:                                WATERBURY HOSPITAL    CT
  ---                                                        
2716:                           DESERT SPRINGS HOSPITAL    NV
2717:                   THREE RIVERS COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    OR
2718: ROBERT WOOD JOHNSON UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL AT RAHWAY    NJ
2719:                             LAREDO MEDICAL CENTER    TX
2720:                     MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH ARKANSAS    AR
```

And the first and second branch could produce the right result, which is like

```
 > head (data)
                               hospital state
1:                                   NA    AK
2:             CRESTWOOD MEDICAL CENTER    AL
3:              ARKANSAS HEART HOSPITAL    AR
4:                 MAYO CLINIC HOSPITAL    AZ
5:    GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER    CA
6: ST MARYS HOSPITAL AND MEDICAL CENTER    CO     
> nrow(data)
[1] 54
```

However, the third condition just COULDN'T do its work. Which produce the error

```
Error in rbindlist(outcome) : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```

And after debugging I found out that the outcome after the condition is something like(which caused the error in the last step)

```
$AK
[1] NA

$AL
$AL[[1]]
[1] "HIGHLANDS MEDICAL CENTER"
```

Differs from the first two which is like...

```
> head(data,2)
$AK
                           hospital state
1: PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER    AK

$AL
                   hospital state
1: CRESTWOOD MEDICAL CENTER    AL
```

So I wonder what's wrong with the third branch.
Could anyone help me out, thank you very much!!!

By the way, I wonder if I could refer to a variable with the same name of another's. Such like when I called `readdata`, I need to pass a argument called `outcome`, which prevents me to use this name as the argument of the `rankall` function(I use `out` instead). I know in JAVA `this.outcome` will help, so how about in R.

Comment: This is an assignment from Coursera, R Programming course so take care that you do not violate the honor code, before you test conditions it would help if you convert them to numeric equivalents, `if (num=="best" index == 1`, `if (num == "worst") index = nrow(x)` `else index = as.numeric(num)`

Comment: Sorry about that, I have changed by hiding some details. Is this OK now? Thank you for your help! And by the way, can you solve my last question concerning naming space.

Comment: The NA for state AK could possibly indicate that for the particular disease AK has no hospital covering it, you could verify this by sub-setting outcome data only for AK. Regarding the 'naming' question, by default the arguments are positionally matched so in rankall function, `rankall(outcome=outcome,...` is a perfectly valid statement

Comment: Actually the NA in AK is something I artificially changed to indicate the situation when NA occurs :). Owing to your help, the 'naming' do work now! It's strange that I tried the same thing but it just didn't work. Thank you veeeeeeeery much

Comment: Seems like an improvement is possible to `rbindlist`. I've linked this question [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1626).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Vivek's help, I have figured it out now.
First is about the mis-performance of the third branch. It'll work properly if I first convert `num`to a number using `as.numeric(num)`. I think it's because the `num` is regarded as a character(since it has possible value of "best" and "worst") that caused the mistake.
The second regarding the naming space is however strange. Though not having performed well in my own test, it just do work after Vivek answer my question. So, that means we can just use the following code, and R will get us the right result.

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best"){
    outcome <- readdata(outcome = outcome)
```

Answer (score 0):

This output below is a warning sign, first element of outcome is just NA, an atomic which is forced to 'bind' with second element which is a list `$AL[[1]]` by the function `rbindlist`

```
$AK
[1] NA

$AL
$AL[[1]]
[1] "HIGHLANDS MEDICAL CENTER"
```

Possible solution:

One way would be to have `data.frame` or `list` output in all three cases `if` condition blocks e.g. with `data.frame`, once `num` is numeric the following should work in all cases, best,worst and intermediate row.

```
sapply(outcome, function(x) data.frame(state=x[num,"state"],hospital=x[num,"hospital"])
```

for cases with no matches the hospital column should have an NA, could you please check if this works

Comment: It does work. And I think your first solution is somehow more simple